What is a reference strain in DNA-DNA hybridization DNA groups?

Results
DNA groups identified:
All intra-group relatedness values are shown in
Table I.
By means of reference strains, most of the DNA groups could be identified as groups described by Bouvet & Grimont (1986) and we
found it most convenient to number them in the same way.
**Tjernberg, I., & Ursing, J. (1989). Clinical strains of Acinetobacter classified by DNA-DNA hybridization. APMIS : acta pathologica, microbiologica, et immunologica Scandinavica, 97(7), 595–605. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1699-0463.1989.tb00449.x**B

Table 1:

Is it decided with the "least square" method, so that the so-called reference strain is well representative of the DNA group despite the possible intraspecies variations among group members?
Does this mean that instead of comparing each member in each DNA group with those of Bouvet & Grimont, they compared only the reference strain of each group?

Have you read the paper any further? It looks like that's just a quote from the abstract. I can't access the paper, but given your reference to least squares as the way of picking them, I'm assuming that you have access. can you provide any further information where they describe how they choose or define reference strains?

The same statement is used elsewhere in the results of the paper. There is no mention of least squares, but I'm guessing.  I'm editing to mention more details.

"Instead, two other reference strains (ATCC 17925 and ATCC 9957) were investigated as representatives of DNA groups 8 and 9 described by Bouvet and Grimont (1). "
https://www.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/ijsem/10.1099/00207713-47-3-837#R1
another study calls these reference strains "representative strains" which makes more sense.

This is a question and answer site about general problems in biology. It is not a journal club, where one has to read a paper to discuss the validity of its results of methods.

What's wrong with you, i was asking what is generally meant by "reference strain" in the context of grouping strains by their DNA relatedness.

Do i have to refer every single study that includes this context so that I'm understandable that I'm not after a single article per se.
